# Weird construct in rodinia 3.1 myocyte benchmark

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp, benchmarking, pragma

I am currently working on a conceptual RISCV SIMT architecture, and our simulator emulates only some needed library calls. We are trying to run `openmp` [rodinia 3.1](http://lava.cs.virginia.edu/Rodinia/download.htm) benchmarks but as we only have `pthread` support, I am trying to translate simple statically scheduled `openmp` code into `pthread` code.

I found in the `myocyte` benchmark this kind of construction:

```
// master.c
void master(params) {
    // declaration of th_id
    int th_id;

    // no initialization of th_id

    #pragma omp parallel private(th_id)
    {
        // code that uses th_id as a "thread id" value
    }
}

// main.c
#pragma omp parallel for
for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
    master(params);
}
```

As I understand, the developers count on the `#pragma` in the `master.c` code to initialize the variable `th_id`, but I couldn't find where it is stated in the openmp documentation. Is assuming `th_id` to be recognized and initialized by ompenmp totaly fine or wrong ?

Comment: Does it use value or address of `th_id` as thread id? AFAIK `private(th_id)` constructs separate `th_id` variable for each thread, but it should'nt really initialize it with anything.

Comment: Opening another `parallel` region within an outer one has no benefit unless OpenMP is set to use nested parallelism. That makes this construct already pretty weird before getting to the issue of the (lack of) initialization of `th_id`...

Comment: I just downloaded and checked the code, and indeed, there is a bug here, with `th_id` used but never set. Actually, gcc catches it with the warning `master.c:66:7: warning: ‘th_id’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]`

Comment: Yes, gcc does catch the uninitialized error, and `th_id` is used for job differentiation (thread 1 to N does something, thread N+1 to M does something else ...), so my question was : is there something not documented with openmp which changes the program and make it correct or is this code wrong ? The compiled binary doesn't seem to be correct as there are nested calls to the "team creation" primitive of openmp. Thank you for your answer, if you think it's a bug i will try to fix it first in my implementation.

Comment: No, nothing in the standard to correct magically the code. It even is doubly wrong at the `private` directive would lose the initialization had it happened (one would have wanted a `firstprivate` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This OpenMP benchmark code is totally broken. There should be something like this at the beginning of the parallel region:

```
th_id = omp_get_thread_num();
```

It obtains the ID of the calling thread and is a number that varies between 0 and the number of threads executing the parallel region minus 1, with 0 corresponding to the master thread.

Again, this code is really broken and seems to have been translated from Fortran. There is an out-of-bounds array access:

```
int th_count[4];

...

#pragma omp parallel private(th_id)
{
    ...
    if (th_id == th_count[4]) {
    ...
}
```

I'd say that you should simply scrap the Myocyte benchmark.

Comment: Ow, didn't see the out of bound. Yes the OMP port is poorly made, not only for this bench. But the bench list is very interesting for us as it contains divergent/uniform highly parallel computation. Thank you for this answer :)

Comment: @Shumush, indeed, Rodinia is a well known benchmark suite for heterogeneous computing systems. Funny thing is that the readme for version 2.4 says "4). Correct many bugs of myocyte OpenMP version." :)